# C++ Boost loop through unknown ptree and list values of attributes

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I'd like to parse random xml files with nodes containing a specific attribute and retrive all the values of this attribute. The use case is that there are many xml with different nodes but the attribute to retrieve is always known.

Here is an example of a file :

```
<node>
 <container>
  <object attribute="value" />
  <object attribute="value" />
 <container/>
 <supercontainer>
  <subcontainer>
   <otherobject attribute="value" />
  <subcontainer/>
 <supercontainer/>
</node>
```

This is what I have for now using boost property_tree but I don't know what to do in the loop:

```
ptree pt;
read_xml(xml_file, pt);
BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &ele, pt)
{
   //NO IDEA
}
```

Ideas welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved it using the following :

```
void recurseManifest(ptree &pt, int lvl)
{
  for (ptree::iterator current = pt.begin(); current != pt.end();)
  {
    try
    {
        std::cout << current->second.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.attribute") << std::endl;
    }
    catch(const boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path &err)
    {
        std::cerr << err.what() << std::endl;    
    }
    assets = recurseManifest(current->second, lvl++);
    ++current;
  }
}
```

Comment: At first glance, it seems uncanonical (error prone, less legible) to put the iterator increment `++current` at the end of the loop scope instead of directly into the `for()` command: `for (ptree::iterator current = pt.begin(); current != pt.end(); ++current) {...}`. What was your reasoning?